# Adaptive Card vertical scrollbar with HTML body in Outlook 365 on the desktop

Tags: html, outlook, adaptive-cards

I have a payload in a script tag inside the head tag of an html page which is sent by C# using SMTP client.  It works just fine, I see the card in Outlook 365 on the desktop but the problem is the height of the card is predefined based on the content thus when people have small screen, there's a vertical scrollbar for the card.  Additionally, the html in the body of the page has also a vertical scrollbar.  I tried with Outlook.com and it doesn't exhibit this behavior

These scrollbars are not desirable.  What would be the correct way to ensure that both the card AND the html doesn't have vertical scrollbar and let Outlook have it's own one so we can scroll using Outlook scrollbar not the card or the HTML

[image]

Here's the payload :

```html
<div>
    <script type="application/adaptivecard+json">
    {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Image",
                        "url": "@LOGO",
                        "size": "Large"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "size": "Medium",
                        "weight": "Bolder",
                        "text": "@ADAPTIVE_CARD_TITLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "weight": "Bolder",
                                        "text": "@SERVICE_TITLE",
                                        "wrap": true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "spacing": "None",
                                        "text": "@SERVICE_DATE",
                                        "isSubtle": true,
                                        "wrap": true
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "spacing": "None",
                        "text": "@REVIEW_TITLE",
                        "wrap": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "separator": true,
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "separator": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "@EMPLOYEE_TITLE"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "separator": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "@EMPLOYEE_VALUE"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "spacing": "None",
                        "separator": true,
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "separator": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "@ACCOUNT_DATE_TITLE"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "separator": true,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "@ACCOUNT_DATE_VALUE"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "actions": [
            {
                "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                "title": "@APPROVE_TITLE",
                "url": "@APPROVE_URL"
            },
            {
                "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                "title": "@REJECT_TITLE",
                "card": {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "id": "comment",
                            "placeholder": "@COMMENT_PLACE_HOLDER",
                            "isMultiline": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                            "title": "@SEND_REASON_TITLE",
                            "url": "@SEND_REASON_URL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                }
            }
        ],
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.0"
    }
    </script>
    <br />
    @BODY
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would comment, but I don't have the rep yet.

I am unable to replicate your issue.  I tested with a long card I made in the designer (just added a bunch of text blocks), and viewed it in OWA (Outlook Web App), and there was only one scroll bar.  I am not on the monthly release channel for the desktop client, so  I can't test that (only compatible for monthly release channel.

Which version of Outlook is rendering the card?

Maybe try putting @BODY inside of head below the script tag?  It might remove one of the scrollbars.

Comment: Oh, I tried in Outlook.com rather than Outlook 365 on the desktop and it works fine.  So I can only assume that the problem is how Outlook 365 renders the email.  I modified my question to include the detail for Outlook 365 on the desktop

Comment: @BODY is a tag to be replaced which is HTML that doesn't fit in the head section.  Since it works in OWA there's no reason to change something and should work in Outlook 2016 as well.  The added HTML must be below the Adaptive card.